# tFPDF - Show mySQL results in header

Tags: php, fpdf

I am trying to show results of mysql in header in tFPDF. So far, i have manage to create the pdf but when i am trying to add the sql data to display, i am getting error.

My code:

```
...
$count = "SELECT
             SUM(app_price_out) AS Outcome,
             SUM(app_price_in) AS Income,
             SUM(app_price) AS Turnover
          FROM tblappointment";

foreach($connection->query($count) as $row) {
    $Outcome= $row['Outcome'];
    $Income= $row['Income'];
    $Turnover= $row['Turnover'];
}

$Total = $Income - $Outcome;
$Debt =  $Turnover - $Income;

class PDF extends tFPDF
{
// Page header
function Header()
{
   $this->SetLeftMargin(9);
   $this->AddFont('Calibri','','Calibri.ttf',true);
   $this->SetFont('Calibri','',9);
   $this->Cell(236,12,'Expenses',0,0);
   $this->Cell(18,6,'Total:',0,0,'R');
   $this->Cell(25,6,number_format($Total,0,",","."),0,0,'R');   ===> Error Line at $Total
   $this->Cell(18,6,'Debt:',0,0,'R');
   $this->Cell(25,6,number_format($Debt,0,",","."),0,0,'R');   ===> Error Line at $Debt
   $this->ln();
}
}
...
```

Error message:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: Total in C:\xampp\...\page.php on line xx
```

Comment: Just saying _“i am getting error”_ is not helpful, not at all. _What_ error?

Comment: @CBroe I noticed that and i was adding it as you where leaving the message.

Comment: That variable does not exist inside that method. You need to go read up on _variable scope_ - https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: @CBroe Added `global $Total, $Debt;` inside `function Header`  and i think it is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of `CBroe`, here is the solution to my problem. Use `global`.

The code:

```
...
function Header()
{
   global $Total, $Debt;  
   $this->SetLeftMargin(9);
   ...
```